# Cordova / Phonegap Globalization vs. navigator.language

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, globalization

I want to implement some mechanism to automatically selecting UI language for my Cordova application. The application is also served from the web (i.e. browser).

From what I see, I can either use the Cordova globalization API plugin ([here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-globalization/)) or, it seems that both Android and iOS support navigator.language which give the device language.

Is there any reason I should opt to use the Cordova plugin over the built in browser/Web View property?

Thanks!

Comment: From what I found there isn't any reason to use the plugin instead of the `navigator.language` property

Comment: Thanks for comment. Do you care to elaborate? Have you found any specific resources or you are discussing your experience with both? I am asking because I played with them and didn't find a major difference and maybe you have...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a series of searches and tests on real devices I can say that the two methods to retrieve the language of the device are more or less the same except for two small differences:

- on **iOS** devices the user can choose separately the language and the region of the device. So, for example, it can choose as a language `italian` but as region `USA`. In this situation, the plugin will return the string `it-US` differently by the `navigator.language` property which will return the string `it-IT` (tested on iOS 11). If you have to know just the language this isn’t a big problem.
- On Android, there is a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=570349#c3) because of which the `navigator.language` is not immediately updated. The new setting is available only after the application is killed. The plugin does not suffer os this bug. A workaround could be to use the `navigator.languages` property which is correctly updated (tested on Android 5.0.2).

If you have to know just the language you can use the information provided by `navigator`  object without any problem.